# What does this regex match? php regex from mediawiki sourcecode

Tags: php, regex, mediawiki

This is a regex from a mediawiki, an open source wiki solution.

```
/\[((http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/|ftp\:\/\/|irc\:\/\/|ircs\:\/\/|gopher\:\/\/|telnet\:\/\/|nntp\:\/\/|worldwind\:\/\/|mailto\:|news\:|svn\:\/\/|git\:\/\/|mms\:\/\/|\/\/)[^][<>"\x00-\x20\x7F\p{Zs}]+)\p{Zs}*([^\]\x00-\x08\x0a-\x1F]*?)\]/Su
```

To me it seems like it matches uri's, but i can't get it to match anything. And im having trouble understanding the last part of the regex, namely.

```
[^][<>"\x00-\x20\x7F\p{Zs}]+)\p{Zs}*([^\]\x00-\x08\x0a-\x1F]*?)\]
```

what the heck does this do?

Any help on decoding this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex matches [external links](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aLinks#External_links) like

```
[http://www.stackoverflow.com]
[https://www.stackoverflow.com StackOverflow]
[ftp://ftp.mozilla.org Mozilla]
```

Answer (score 3):

`[^][<>"\x00-\x20\x7F\p{Zs}]`
Is a negated character class that matches any character but: `][<>"`, the ASCII character range `\x00-\x20`, the ASCII character `\x7F` and whitespace (`p{Zs}` is a [Unicode Character Property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) that matches any kind of spaces character)

`\p{Zs}*` matches any kind of spaces character 0 or more times

`[^\]\x00-\x08\x0a-\x1F]`
Is a negated character class that matches any character but `]`, the ASCII character ranges `\x00-\x08` and `\x0a-\x1F`

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong. You have to separate `[^][<>"\x00-\x20\x7F\p{Zs}]` into `[^]` and `[<>"\x00-\x20\x7F\p{Zs}]` given that the `]` closes the character class and is not escaped. As such it first matches *any* character and then it matches the character specified by the second group.

Comment: No, `[^][<>"\x00-\x20\x7F\p{Zs}]` is one character class.  The first `]` is treated as a literal `]` because it's the first character listed (or first after the negating `^`, in this case), just like `-` would be.  It's a nice little stealth feature that I wish were supported by all flavors.

Comment: @AlanMoore thanks, I knew I saw somewhere that it is defined that way, I tested on Regexr after poke's comment and there this feature is not available. But the regex makes only sense with this interpretation. Rolled back my answer.

Comment: What @poke said is true in JavaScript--I think it's part of the ECMAScript spec.  Since RegExr is written in ActionScript3 (another ECMAScript implementation) it also follows the "empty class" rule.  (I wasn't sure which way RegExr would go, since AS3 farms out its regex support to the PCRE lib same as PHP.  But on a PHP-based tester like [this one](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php), it works as I described.)

Comment: Oh, that’s weird. Didn’t know about that and thought `[^]` would always match anything on its own. One learns something new every day :o (but I would argue that escaping the square brackets would be more distinguishable…)